# How do I create a rule for custom flag replacement with C shell?

Tags: shell-script, tcsh, command-substitution, csh

I want to have the following behavior with grep:

```
grep --java <rest of the command>
```

Where --java would either dynamically convert to --include=*.java or internally be equivalent to it. Is there a way to do this in my .cshrc file? I tried using the complete command but I can't seem to have the replacement work on the current word.

Comment: This would typically be done with a shell function wrapper around `grep`, which might be tricky in a shell like `tcsh`, which only provides aliases. `ack` might be another option, as it has `--type-set` to specify filenames to search.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a different syntax (which is also shorter and easier to type in this case), just create an alias for it. Add this to your `~/.cshrc`:

```
alias jgrep grep --include="*.java"
```

Then, you can run something like:

```
jgrep foo *
```

And it will run

```
grep --include="*java" foo *
```

Comment: But I would like the behavior to be dynamic, like the syntax in complete command. So a given word in a set of words I want to behave like this would equate to going from --<word> to --include=\*<word>.

Comment: @CrisRR I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Like a substitution rule, that says if grep followed by --{gradle | groovy | java} then -> --include=\*.{gradle | groovy | java}, but only have this behaviour for the ones I declare in the list.

Comment: @CrisRR well, I would just have 3 aliases, once for each of gradle, groove and java. I don't see what you gain by having it dynamically expanded.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you can do in `tcsh`.

Your options are:

- Use an alias, as already mentioned by terdon:

  ```
  alias jgrep grep --include="*.java"
  ```
- Set up a completion pattern. For example:

  ```
  complete grep 'c/--/(complete)/' 'n/--complete/(*.java *.rb *.py)/'
  ```

  This will allow you to type `grep --<Tab><Tab>j<Tab>`.
- Use a variable:

  ```
  set java = '--include=*.java'  
  grep -r "$java" foo
  ```

  Personally, I wouldn't necessarily consider that to be easier.

Finally, I find that [the_silver_searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) is a lot more useful and faster for "grepping" code trees. It's something you might want to check out.